# I want to implement hector SLAM on the raspberry Pi 2

Tags: ros, slam, raspberrypi, xv-11, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone I am very new to robotics and embedded systems. My goal is to build a small indoor ground robot that uses a Neato XV - 11 Lidar to build a map of its surroundings.  I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 for interfacing the robot with the Lidar.

I am completely lost on where to start. I was able to find the following package for hector SLAM http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam but I'm not too sure where to go from there. How do I install ROS on the Raspberry Pi 2? What version of ROS should I use and why? How do I send information from the Pi to my laptop? Do I need to install ROS on my laptop as well?

I just need some advice on how to start and where to look.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225457/i-want-to-implement-hector-slam-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/) by [jaymo3141](https://answers.ros.org/users/25794/jaymo3141/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2016-01-31**:
search answers.ros.org  or   with a search machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,
I used raspberry pi 2 to make a robot with SLAM before.

Due to "rviz segmentation fault" error, I change my platform to tegra TK1.

But some kindness people have told me how to solve it(and I am still not solve it now).

so I can only share with you my notes.

[Demo on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsq4Q8xdWA0)

[My blog (with step of how to use hector slam)](https://hollyqood.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/ros-slam-2-hector-slam-2d%E5%9C%B0%E5%9C%96%E5%BB%BA%E7%BD%AE/)

[Blog 2](http://hollyqood.logdown.com/posts/336734)

And your first step should be [how to install ROS on Raspberry Pi 2](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi).

Hope that can help you :))

Alyson

---

Originally posted by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) with karma: 196 on 2016-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1